# getting blank value using this variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I get a blank value on click of anchor tag using this operator. I have multiple divs with same class thats why I used `.each()` function, I dont know where am I doing wrong.
Output should be, on click one the first value should appear in input and so on
here is my code

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.main').each(function(){
    $('a',this).click(function(){
      $val = $('p',this).text();
      $("#aarti").val($val);
      alert($val);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <p>value one</p>
  <div id="sub" style="display: block;">
    <p><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myContactModal">CLICK ONE</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="main">
  <p>value two</p>
  <div id="sub" style="display: block;">
    <p><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myContactModal">CLICK TWO</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="main">
  <p>value three</p>
  <div id="sub" style="display: block;">
    <p><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myContactModal">CLICK THREE</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="main">
  <p>value four</p>
  <div id="sub" style="display: block;">
    <p><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myContactModal">CLICK FOUR</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
<input type="text" id="aarti" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort but I dont want the value of anchor tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need traverse up to parent `main` element, then target its child `p` element

```js
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   $('.main a ').click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var $val = $(this).closest('.main').children('p').text();
     $("#aarti").val($val);
   });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <p>value three</p>
  <div id="sub" style="display: block;">
    <p><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myContactModal">CLICK THREE</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="main">
  <p>value four</p>
  <div id="sub" style="display: block;">
    <p><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myContactModal">CLICK FOUR</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>


<input type="text" id="aarti" />
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to loop through the main class. Just click on the main you want and `this` will get it and can do the rest for you

Try this:

```
 $(document).on('click','.main',function(){
   $("#aarti").val($(this).find('p').html());
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.main').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
      var $val = $(this).find('p').text();           
      alert($val);
});
```

Should help